# Have Visual Studio share a namespace with multiple service references

Tags: .net, wcf, service-reference

Is there any way possible short of hand-coding the Reference.cs file, to get Visual Studio to allow multiple service references to share a namespace?

I am developing a client application that makes use of several services that are part of the same solution.  Something along the lines of the Project Service Interface (PSI) API Microsoft has for MS-Project Server.  Rather than have a different namespace for each individual service reference, such as:

```
MyProject.ProjectService.ProjectServiceClient
MyProject.ResourceService.ResourceServiceClient
MyProject.TimesheetService.TimesheetServiceClient
```

it would be nice if we could throw them all into a single namespace, like:

```
MyProject.Services.ProjectServiceClient
MyProject.Services.ResourceServiceClient
MyProject.Services.TimesheetServiceClient
```

Along with this comes the ability to share common code.  For instance if any of these services exposed the same data contract.  Right now, if I want to write code that my client can use I have to create a separate version for each service proxy because the common contract exists in three different namespaces.  See where I'm going?

It is possible?

**UPDATE**

Let's assume that I don't have access to the service code (cuz I don't) which means that a shared class library is not an option.  What are my choices in this case?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? And are you using Service References, or a Web Reference?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and adding a Service Reference.  (Use of the PSI was just for the example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place these common classes into a class library which is shared by both the services and the clients. Then, Visual Studio will not generate classes for each service reference, but will instead use the common class library.

Comment: Yea, I realize that.  I'm just hoping that there's a way to make it a bit cleaner - or maybe better put: automatic.

Comment: This is a wonderful technique and has many benefits, if you control both the server and client sides of your services.  I think my favorite feature of this technique is that you no longer have to maintain those gawdawful Service References dirs and Reference.cs files, egads, those are simply painful.

Comment: @Chris: you still have the Reference.cs files, they just have less in them.

Comment: @John Saunders, I would go the extra mile and make your very own Reference.cs files.  That way you can get compile time errors when someone else on your happy dev team changes the contract and forgets to update all client references (this is much preferred than discovering broken contract changes at runtime ;-)

Comment: @Chris: I would use automated post-build functional tests, if at all possible, so would discover the problem during a nightly build. Takes some infrastructure, but well worth it.

Comment: @John Saunders, fair enough, that would work perfectly well, and should also work well in a CI environment, I'm hoping.

Comment: Another aspect is when the services aren't available (e.g. developed by a 3rd party) so sharing a common class library isn't possible.

Comment: And, unfortunately, company policy is to leverage all of the built-in tooling as much as possible.  So while I am perfectly comfortable with the idea of a hand-coded Reference.cs-like solution, we are forced to use the Add Service Reference feature.

Comment: @Son: "Add Service Reference" works with the class library solution. You are correct that this doesn't work for third-party services.